# MockMvc returning 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mocking, automated-tests

I wrote controller which used different values for each mapping. Now I refractored it to use the same value for all mappings, however I have no idea how to make test work, because it returns 404 on each of them.

Here is my controller:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    DbService dbService;
    @Autowired
    TaskMapper taskMapper;

    @GetMapping(value = "/tasks")
    public List<TaskDto> getTasks() {
        return taskMapper.mapToTaskDtoList(dbService.getAllTask());
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/tasks/{id}")
    public TaskDto getTask(@PathVariable Long id) throws TaskNotFoundException {
        return taskMapper.mapToTaskDto(dbService.getTask(id).orElseThrow(TaskNotFoundException::new));
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/tasks/{id}")
    public void deleteTask(@PathVariable Long id) {
        dbService.deleteTask(id);
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/tasks")
    public TaskDto updateTask(@RequestBody TaskDto taskDto) {
        return taskMapper.mapToTaskDto(dbService.saveTask(taskMapper.mapToTask(taskDto)));
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/tasks", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void createTask(@RequestBody TaskDto taskDto) {
        dbService.saveTask(taskMapper.mapToTask(taskDto));
    }
}
```

And my tests:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(TaskController.class)
public class TaskControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private DbService dbService;

    @MockBean
    private TaskMapper taskMapper;

    @Test
    public void shouldFetchAllTasks() throws Exception {
        //Given
        List<TaskDto> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        tasks.add(new TaskDto(1L, "test", "testing"));
        tasks.add(new TaskDto(2L, "test2", "still_testing"));

        when(taskMapper.mapToTaskDtoList(dbService.getAllTask())).thenReturn(tasks);
        //When & Then
        mockMvc.perform(get("/v1/task/tasks").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].title", is("test")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].content", is("testing")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].id", is(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].title", is("test2")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].content", is("still_testing")));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFetchGivenTask() throws Exception {
        //Given
        List<TaskDto> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        tasks.add(new TaskDto(1L, "test", "testing"));
        tasks.add(new TaskDto(2L, "test2", "still_testing"));

        when(dbService.getTask(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(new Task(2L, "test2", "still_testing")));
        when(taskMapper.mapToTaskDto(anyObject())).thenReturn(tasks.get(1));
        //When & Then
        mockMvc.perform(get("/v1/task/tasks/{id}", "2")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.title", is("test2")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content", is("still_testing")));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldUpdateTask() throws Exception {
        //Given
        TaskDto taskDto = new TaskDto(1L, "test", "testing");
        TaskDto updatedTaskDto = new TaskDto(1L, "updated task", "even more testing");

        when(taskMapper.mapToTaskDto(dbService.saveTask(taskMapper.mapToTask(taskDto)))).thenReturn(updatedTaskDto);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonContent = gson.toJson(taskDto);

        //When & Then
        mockMvc.perform(put("/v1/task/tasks")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(jsonContent))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.title", is("updated task")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content", is("even more testing")));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDeleteTask() throws Exception {
        //Given
        //When & Then
        mockMvc.perform(delete("/v1/task/tasks/{id}","1"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateTask() throws Exception {
        //Given
        //When & Then
        mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/task/tasks")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content("{\"title\":\"another test\"," +
                        "\"content\":\"keep on testing\"}"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

All test result in 404 and following:

> at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
>       at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:619)
>       at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:195)
>       at com.crud.tasks.controller.TaskControllerTest.shouldFetchGivenTask(TaskControllerTest.java:74)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url - `/v1/task/tasks` is not present in any of the request mapping in your controller. your class level controller has `/v1` request mapping and your method level request mapping has `/tasks` and not `/task` so you are getting 404 not found error.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. My eyes are a bit tired after few hours so couldn't notice such a simple think. Sorry for trouble.